# System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'mssqllocaldb

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have changed the project URL in my project  on page of debug properties and then received an error as

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Keyword not supported: 'mssqllocaldb; attachdbfilename'."

Could you please advise how i can fix this problem?

I use code-first on this project. Also i got an error while changing URL as

> "To keep these settings you need to configure the virtual
>   directory.Would you like to create the virtual directory now?"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SQL CE does not support *attachdbfilename* . Have you tried this?

```
<add name="MyLocalConnection" 
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|/mssqllocaldb.sdf;
Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your connection string. 
Example of valid connection string for MSSQL server 2014+:

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True`